# the arrt name GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE in Android sdk

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbo

I trying to use the FBO by Android OpenGLES 2.0
I can render to a color texture then render to the screen
now I want to render to a depth texture! but I didnt found the attr name GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE. is it not support in opengles?

Answer (score 4):

`GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` has nothing to do with rendering to a depth texture. That's old fixed-function stuff from desktop OpenGL 2.1. Rendering to a depth texture only requires creating a texture with a depth internal format, and then attaching it to the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` of an FBO.

Comment: Is there a list of what is not "modern" OpenGL and what is? There are so many things that I don't know and I hate to go on a wild goose chase just because I didn't know that that API was fixed function...

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: Generally speaking, any [OpenGL learning materials that use core profile OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) or OpenGL ES 2.0 will tell you that up-front. So just avoid the ones that don't say what version of OpenGL they're using. As for a list, you can always use the [OpenGL reference pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) or [GL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page) to know what's core and what is not.

Comment: ...and here I was just thinking what exactly is the meaning of the term "core". Clearly this is the answer to my question.